# Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol while using Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary, delegates, protocols

I am coding in swift. I have written a protocol

```
@objc protocol ServerDelegate {
    optional func onDownloadDataComplete (downloadedData data : [Dictionary<String,Any>],result : ResultType,error : String)
}
```

First I received "Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C" for my enum but I fixed it by adding @objc. Now I am receiving this for Array of Dictionary. How to fix it?

Comment: downloadedData data : [NSDictionary]

Comment: `Any` cannot be represented in obj-c. What are you using your dictionary for? I highly doubt you're not able to be any more type specific than `Any`.

Comment: My dictionary contains values of different types such as string, int, nsdata, UIImage.

Comment: What is your use case?  It sounds like you have an XY Problem.

Comment: @kashif789us Why do you need object and value types?  Just make it `AnyObject` and use `NSNumber` or `NSValue` for any values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @originaluser2 said `Any` cannot be represented in `@objc` so I created a new class, added data members which I needed, inherited it with `NSObject` and returned its array instead of dictionary and all is good now.