# Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am getting "Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C" error while making this method

```
 @objc public protocol ShareSecurityQuestionProtocol {
 func setResultofSecurityQuestion(valueSent: [NSMutableDictionary]) -> (success: Bool, error:  NSString)
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054049/method-cannot-be-a-member-of-an-objc-protocol-while-using-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples cannot be represented in Obj-C, so you cannot make your function return a tuple. Create an Obj-C type that holds both fields you want to return and return that type instead of a tuple.

```
@objc public class ShareSecurityQuestionResult: NSObject {
    let success: Bool
    let error: String

    init(success: Bool, error: String) {
        self.success = success
        self.error = error
    }
}

@objc public protocol ShareSecurityQuestionProtocol {
    func setResultofSecurityQuestion(valueSent: [NSMutableDictionary]) -> ShareSecurityQuestionResult
}
```